# Running tasks inside LXD container through ansible

Tags: ansible, lxd

Trying to figure out the best way to get ansible to do its magic within the containers. Was thinking of using ssh in each container, but then that is server-dependent. or I have to come via the proxy which seems like more work than should be necessary.
Again, I am already creating containers, deleting etc… I am talking about running commands within the container with ansible not via lxc exec containername bash which I can do now.
Anyone figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible (SSH + LXD) plugin](https://serverfault.com/questions/1087866/ansible-ssh-lxd-plugin)

Comment: Can I ask why you want to? What is it that needs doing to these containers that requires Ansible?

Comment: I am trying to create a project for hosting platform. For that, i am using LXD containers and Ansible. As i m having issue to run task inside LXD container through ansible. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

taken from https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lxc_container_module.html#examples

you can try the following:

```
- name: Run a complex command within a "running" container
  community.general.lxc_container:
    name: test-container-started
    container_command: |
      apt-get update
      apt-get install -y curl wget vim apache2
      echo 'hello world.' | tee /opt/started
      if [[ -f "/opt/started" ]]; then
          echo 'hello world.' | tee /opt/found-started
      fi
```

Comment: I am running lxd container and it does not seems to be working with the above commands.

Comment: as this is a part of official documentation I suggest you open an issue on official github of ansible community.general.lxc_container module with detailed logs as to what is failing and how

Answer (score 0):

`community.general.lxc_container` is definitely deprecated and does not support lxd, since it point to bin/lxc-create hard-coded it can not run just commands, maybe commands can be run only during creations.

But is still the only working tool for creating, stooping, and starting the containers in Ansible.

There is a reason why it is not fixed or adjusted to lxd.

There is another easier way to do it, see this official lxd demo [LXD and Ansible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ROBfRKSiI8).
Shortly, it is based on the connection type changing from 'ssh' to 'lxd'.
Additional pre-configuration is needed when connecting remotely.

```
#ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory = hosts.yml

#hosts.yml
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: lxd
    ansible_user: root
    ansible_become: no
  children:
    local:
      vars:
        ansible_lxd_remote: local
        ansible_lxd_project: demo
      hosts:
        c1:
        v1:
    yyy:
      vars:
        ansible_lxd_remote: tuxedo
      hosts:
        lxc-tuxedo-1:
    xxx:
      vars:
        ansible_connection: ssh
        ansible_user: ada
      hosts:
        alu-rpi:  

#demo.yml
- name: Setup apache
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: install the apache package
      apt:
        name: apache2
        state: present

    - name: Make sure apache is running
      systemd:
        name: apache2.service
        state: started

# bash
ansible-playbook demo.yml -l yyy # lxd container via lxd connection
ansible-playbook demo.yml -l xxx # rasberry pi via ssh
```